How to exclude users when eventName exactly matches {event name} at any point in time using API?
I am using BetaAnalyticsDataClient with python, and unable to filter users that have done this event out from the data. I have been able to download the full data OR users that have done this event but not the thing that i am trying to do.
Basically I have an event which I use to identify users that have logged in to the website.
I have attached two photos of what i am trying to/not trying to replicate from google analytics web interface.
Goal --> trying to replicate this
I have tried something like this and variations of it:
        dimension_filter=FilterExpression(
            not_expression=FilterExpression(
                filter=Filter(
                    field_name="eventName",
                    string_filter=Filter.StringFilter(value="login_link_click"),
                )
            )
        ),
    )

but its returning different data. only getting these results for this filter
